# PHP code inside Jquery append() function

Tags: php, jquery

I want to add PHP code inside my jQuery `append()` function.

I have tried the following code but it's not working. 
I think I'm missing something.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
      $("#addMore").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#fieldList").append("<tr><td><label><?php echo get_phrase('select_item');?></label><select name='item[]' class='form-control' > <option value=''><?php echo get_phrase('select_item');?></option><?php $categories = $this->db->get_where('item', array('category1' => 'STATIONARY'))->result_array(); foreach ($categories as $row):?><option value='<?php echo $row['componentId'];?>'><?php echo $row['itemName'];?></option>
              <?php endforeach;?></select></td><td><label><?php echo get_phrase('amount ');?></label><input type='text' name='amount[]' class='form-control'></td></tr>");

      });
});
</script>
```

Comment: What's the issue? Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: I sugest you rethink your design. Also, escape values otherwise you're prone to XSS hacks.

Comment: lets take a minute for the death of serverside/clientside code :(

Comment: i get Uncaught ReferenceError: add_fields is not defined(…)

Comment: JavaScript is client side, while php is server side. You're basically asking a client side script to execute server side code, and that's not possible. Your best bet is to separate the two things, maybe with your js calling with ajax a php page, which will return the data you'll write with standard js functions.

Comment: @hypnos not necessarily. If the code snippet above is inside a *.php file the php code gets parsed before the script is passed to the browser or am I missing something?

Comment: @simon yeah, you're right. Wasn't considering this, but it's very probably the case. Thank you for your correction.

Comment: This code looks very messy. You are putting HTML inside PHP inside JS and it's close to unreadable. Consider rendering an HTML (hidden) template with placeholders and doing the looping in javascript. If the code is more readable it will be easier for you and us to debug it.

Comment: @NishanSingha are you absolutely sure that the error occurs in this part of your code? I don't see `add_fields` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your data source is most probably inaccessible. Try pulling your data source on top of your page.php. You can organise your page similar to the example below.

```
<?php

function getProduct($id) {
    $products = [
        '1' => [
            'name' => 'product1',
            'price' => 'price1',
        ],
        '2' => [
            'name' => 'product2',
            'price' => 'price2',
        ],
    ];

    return $products[$id];
}

?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log('<?= getProduct(1)['name']; ?>');
    console.log('<?= getProduct(1)['price']; ?>');
</script>
```